# How do I do to install playORM in a local maven repo?

Tags: playorm

I cloned the last official repository version and tried to run:
./build publish

in my ubuntu. However, I got the errors bellow.
I have a maven project and I need to add a dependency to playORM, but I don't know how to do it.

```
checkstyle:
     [echo] MAX CHECKSTYLE ERRORS ALLOWED=0
[checkstyle] Running Checkstyle 4.1 on 276 files

all:

publish:
[ivy:publish] :: delivering :: alvazan#orm;working@mvalle-POS-EIH61CE :: 20121019172025 :: integration :: Fri Oct 19 17:20:25 BRT 2012
[ivy:publish]   delivering ivy file to /tmp/playorm/input/libinclude/ivy.xml
[ivy:publish] :: publishing :: alvazan#orm

BUILD FAILED
/tmp/playorm/bldfiles/build.xml:55: impossible to publish artifacts for alvazan#orm;working@mvalle-POS-EIH61CE: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown resolver local
    at org.apache.ivy.core.publish.PublishEngine.publish(PublishEngine.java:168)
    at org.apache.ivy.Ivy.publish(Ivy.java:611)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyPublish.doExecute(IvyPublish.java:311)
    at org.apache.ivy.ant.IvyTask.execute(IvyTask.java:277)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 1 minute 49 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be running the publish target.  That is created so we can publish to the open source nexus repository so everyone can depend on an officially released version.

That said, do you also want to be able to publish to a local repository.  We could probably create a new generic target that you would have to supply parameters to like host, path, username, password, version, etc. etc.  though our intent is users just depend on the released released up in the global maven repository.

Comment: Ok, I actually have been able to install it in my local repository following these instructions: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/ I created a eclipse launch to install playorm as a dependency in my local repo with version 0.0.1, using m2e eclipse plugin. The launch is very simple and is here: https://github.com/mvallebr/playorm/blob/master/bldfiles/playorm.launch